# Passing Umlauts to jQuery UI Dialog

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, diacritics

I'm trying to set some text to [jQuery UI Dialog](https://jqueryui.com/dialog/).

When passing a text with Umlauts, it appears in the body as intended, but in the title as `&uuml;`.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  zeigeDialog("&uuml;", "&uuml;");
})

function zeigeDialog(title, message) {
  $("#dialog").dialog({
    modal: true,
    title: title,
    buttons: {
      Ok: function() {
        $(this).dialog('close');
      }
    }
  });
  $("#dialog_Text").html(message);
}
```

[Here is a fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/9z9ov06w/2/).

Comment: Looks like that UI widget uses `.text()` instead of `.html()` for the title, either deliberately or as a bug.  Is simply using utf-8 `zeigeDialog("ü", "ü");` an option?

Comment: @DanielBeck: I don't know. Can I be sure, it will be displayed properly in all browsers?

Comment: UTF-8 is the default encoding for html5, so it should work. You'll need to make sure your whole pipeline supports that encoding too (if this'll be stored in a database, for example, the db needs to be in utf-8 too).  Most tools default to utf-8 these days, this stuff is a lot easier than it used to be...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just create a dummy element, set it's html using your title and retrieve the text. Then use that to set the title

```
...
title: $('<span></span>').html(title).text(),
...
```

---

Fiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/e7e07ajr/